# Error when trying to send an email with C#

Tags: c#, smtp, windows-server

Im a bit new with C# and I'm trying to send an email with a console app, this is my code:

```
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

        String emailUsr = "admin@email.com";
        String emailPassword = "password";

        mail.From = new MailAddress(emailUsr);
        mail.To.Add("usremail@email.com");

        mail.Subject = "test";

        string body = "test";


        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient()
        {
            Host = "express server"
            , Port = 25
            , UseDefaultCredentials = false
            , Credentials = new NetworkCredential(emailUsr , emailPassword)
            , EnableSsl = true
        };

        try
        {
            smtp.Send(mail);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
```

[Error displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dqp6.png)

I don't know if it is an error with my code or with the server configuration.

Comment: Likely you are using the wrong configuration, have you tried port 465? Though exactly what you need can only be known by you, and the email server you are communicating with

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen an email server support SSL over port 25. LIke @MichaelRandall said, you should probably be using a different port.

Comment: Looks to me like that server has an inbound IP white list restriction. It doesn't recognize your IP so you are being rejected. Are you able to connect to the server using a standard email client (e.g. Outlook Express)?